# My code is wrong? I can't seem to find the answer

Tags: python, syntax, file-handling

Question is:

> Create a text file named team.txt and store 8 football team names and their best player, separate the player from the team name by a comma.
> Create a program that reads from the text file and displays a random
> team name and the first letter of the player’s first name and the first letter of their surname.

[image: syntax error image here]

```
import random
teamList = open("team.txt", "r")
data = teamList.readlines()
randomChoice = random.choice(range(8))
teamName =[["arsenal"],["tottenham"],["chelsea"],["westham"],["city"],["united"],["barcelona"],["liverpool"]]
player =[["kane"],["messi"],["ronaldo"],["ronaldino"],["ibrahimovic"],["neymar"],["salah"],["hazard"]]
for lines in data:
    split = lines.split(',')
    teamName.append(split[0])
    player.append(split[1])
teamName = teamName[randomChoice]
letters = player[randomChoice]
print("\nThe team is ", teamName)
splitLetters = letters.append('')
print("And the first letter of the player’s firstname and surname is")

for x in range(len(splitLetters)):
    print((splitLetters[x][0]).upper())
```

Comment: If you are only having one player per team, than you could do this using a `.csv` and the function `read_csv()` from `pandas`.

Comment: where would i put the `read_csv()`  function

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the error message as text. There's no easy way to try copy it into our answers and it won't show up in future Google searches. See: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
splitLetters = letters.append('')
```

The issue is .append() does not return any value, so splitLetters is `None` and therefore doesn't have a length. To use .append(), you need to append directly to the string (i.e letters.append('t') would append the string 't' to letters, but wouldn't return a value)

However, this is not necessary since you are appending an empty string '' to letters. Try removing the line `splitLetters = letters.append('')` changing the second last line to:

```
for x in range(len(letters)):
```